# jQuery focus() not producing dotted outline or selecting correctly-accessibility

Tags: jquery, navigation, focus

I have been tasked with producing similar navigation accessibility tabbing to what can be seen on this Sony site: http://www.sony.co.uk/pro/hub/home

That bit I'm interested in is when you hover over "Products" for example you'll notice that the first image in the menu gets a thin dotted line around it. From here if you use the tab key on your keyboard you can then tab through the menu options. And if you then hover a different main menu item the dotted line will then appear over the first image in that menu.

The code below is my attempt to achieve this effect which appears to be a similar way that Sony is doing it, as I looked at their jquery-main.js file, however mind does not work.

Here is my code (markup first) to try and do the same.

```
<div class="main-navigation@(Request.QueryString.Get("breadcrumb") != "1" ? "" : " type-2")">
<ul class="cf">

    <li class="mmnu"><a href="javascript:;">Products</a></li>

    <li class="mmnu"><a href="javascript:;">Your Business</a></li>

    <li class="mmnu"><a href="javascript:;">Where To Buy</a></li>

    <li class="mmnu"><a href="javascript:;">Support</a> </li>

    <li class="mmnu"><a href="javascript:;">Contact Us</a></li>

    <li class="mmnu"><a href="javascript:;">Partners</a></li>

</ul>

    <div class="expand-SD@(Request.QueryString.Get("breadcrumb") != "1" ? " type-2" : "")">

    <div class="category-navigation-SD SD-m1"><!-- PRODUCTS -->

        <div class="row-separator-SD cf">

            <div class="col-1x4 frst">
                <a href="#"><img width="50" height="24" width="50" height="24" src="assets/images/content/_0049_channel_partners.svg" alt="Category Thumbnail" /></a>
                <h2><a href="#">Broadcast & Pro A/V</a></h2>
                <ul>
                    <li><a id="ezone" onclick="s_objectID='topdropdown:Digital Signage';try{sc_navMethod('topdropdown');}catch(err){}" href="Iframe_Page?url=popup_my_subscriptions.cshtml&amp;iW=921&amp;iH=810" class="fancybox.iframe">New iframe</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">HD & SD Camcorders</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Camera Systems</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">HD Decks, Recorders & VTRs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Professional Media</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Production Switchers & Image Processing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Production Monitors</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Professional Audio</a></li>
                </ul>
                <a href="#" class="more">More ></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1x4">
                <a href="#"><img width="50" height="24" src="assets/images/content/_0050_prime_support.svg" alt="Category Thumbnail" /></a>
                <h2><a href="#">Broadcast Solutions</a></h2>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Outside Broadcast</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">News Aquisition & Production</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Studios</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Content Management & Distribution</a></li>
                </ul>
                <a href="#" class="more">More ></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1x4">
                <a href="#"><img width="50" height="24" src="assets/images/content/_0047_projector.svg" alt="Category Thumbnail" /></a>
                <h2><a href="#">4K Digital Cinema</a></h2>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">4K Digital Cinema Projectors</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">High Frame Rate Software</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Theatre Management Solutions</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Entertainment Access Glasses</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Accessories</a></li>
                </ul>
                <a href="#" class="more">More ></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1x4 lst">
                <a href="#"><img width="50" height="24" src="assets/images/content/_0048_sales_enquiries_2.svg" alt="Category Thumbnail" /></a>
                <h2><a href="#">Video Security</a></h2>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Cameras</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Recorders</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Monitoring Software</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Digital Encoders</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Video Security Monitors</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Accessories</a></li>
                </ul>
                <a href="#" class="more">More ></a>
            </div>                                  


        </div><!-- ROW SEPARATOR END -->

        <div class="row-separator-SD cf">

            <div class="col-1x4 frst">
                <a href="#"><img width="50" height="24" src="assets/images/content/_0024_medical.svg" alt="Category Thumbnail" /></a>
                <h2><a href="#">Medical</a></h2>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">3D Medical Products</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Radiology Imagers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Printers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Print Media</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Monitors</a></li>
                </ul>
                <a href="#" class="more">More ></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1x4">
                <a href="#"><img width="50" height="24" src="assets/images/content/_0025_video_conferencing.svg" alt="Category Thumbnail" /></a>
                <h2><a href="#">Video Conferencing</a></h2>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">tbc</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">tbc</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">tbc</a></li>
                </ul>
                <a href="#" class="more">More ></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1x4 lst">
                <a href="#"><img width="50" height="24" src="assets/images/content/_0028_semi_conductors.svg" alt="Category Thumbnail" /></a>
                <h2><a href="#">Semiconductors</a></h2>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Technical Library Login</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Technical Library Registration</a></li>
                </ul>
                <a href="#" class="more">More ></a>
            </div>


        </div><!-- ROW SEPARATOR END -->

        <div class="SD-nsh">

            <a href="#" class="SD-cls"><img width="80" height="40" src="assets/images/content/menu_close.svg" alt="Menu close image" /></a>

        </div>

    </div><!-- PRODUCTS END -->
```

jQuery

```
$('.main-navigation ul li.mmnu').click(function(){
                var tabNum = $(this).index();
                if (!allClosedSD())
                {
                    animateToSizeSD(tabNum);
                    fadeInCurrentSD(tabNum);
                    // code below I though would focus on the first link in the menu
                    $('.SD-m1 div ul li:first a').focus();
                    console.log(tabNum);
                    console.log('enter activated');
                }
                else
                {
                    if ($('.main-navigation ul li:eq(' + tabNum + ')').hasClass('hover'))
                    {
                        console.log('this one closes it');
                        closeMnuSD();
                    } else {
                        fadeInCurrentSD(tabNum);
                        animateToSizeSD(tabNum);
                        console.log('live swtich activated');
                    }
                }
                $('.main-navigation').addClass('open');
            });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8mnp8/

EDIT: animateToSizeSD() code included.

```
function animateToSizeSD(tabNum){
                if (tabNum == "0" && !allClosedSD()) { 
                    $('.expand-SD').show().animate({height:SDHarr[0]},'slow');
                    $('.main-navigation ul li').removeClass('hover');
                    $('.main-navigation ul li:eq(0)').addClass('hover');
                } else if (tabNum == "0")
                {
                    $('.expand-SD').delay(400).show().animate({height:SDHarr[0]},'slow');
                    $('.main-navigation ul li').removeClass('hover');
                    $('.main-navigation ul li:eq(0)').addClass('hover');
                }
                if (tabNum == "1" && !allClosedSD()) { 
                    $('.expand-SD').show().animate({height:SDHarr[1]},'slow');
                    $('.main-navigation ul li').removeClass('hover');
                    $('.main-navigation ul li:eq(1)').addClass('hover');
                } else if (tabNum == "1")
                {
                    $('.expand-SD').delay(400).show().animate({height:SDHarr[1]},'slow');
                    $('.main-navigation ul li').removeClass('hover');
                    $('.main-navigation ul li:eq(1)').addClass('hover');
                }
                if (tabNum == "2" && !allClosedSD()) { 
                    $('.expand-SD').show().animate({height:SDHarr[2]},'slow');
                    $('.main-navigation ul li').removeClass('hover');
                    $('.main-navigation ul li:eq(2)').addClass('hover');
                } else if (tabNum == "2")
                {
                    $('.expand-SD').delay(400).show().animate({height:SDHarr[2]},'slow');
                    $('.main-navigation ul li').removeClass('hover');
                    $('.main-navigation ul li:eq(2)').addClass('hover');
                }
                if (tabNum == "3" && !allClosedSD()) { 
                    $('.expand-SD').show().animate({height:SDHarr[3]},'slow');
                    $('.main-navigation ul li').removeClass('hover');
                    $('.main-navigation ul li:eq(3)').addClass('hover');
                } else if (tabNum == "3")
                {
                    $('.expand-SD').delay(400).show().animate({height:SDHarr[3]},'slow');
                    $('.main-navigation ul li').removeClass('hover');
                    $('.main-navigation ul li:eq(3)').addClass('hover');
                }
                if (tabNum == "4" && !allClosedSD()) { 
                    $('.expand-SD').show().animate({height:SDHarr[4]},'slow');
                    $('.main-navigation ul li').removeClass('hover');
                    $('.main-navigation ul li:eq(4)').addClass('hover');
                } else if (tabNum == "4")
                {
                    $('.expand-SD').delay(400).show().animate({height:SDHarr[4]},'slow');
                    $('.main-navigation ul li').removeClass('hover');
                    $('.main-navigation ul li:eq(4)').addClass('hover');
                }
                if (tabNum == "5" && !allClosedSD()) { 
                    $('.expand-SD').show().animate({height:SDHarr[5]},'slow');
                    $('.main-navigation ul li').removeClass('hover');
                    $('.main-navigation ul li:eq(5)').addClass('hover');
                } else if (tabNum == "5")
                {
                    $('.expand-SD').delay(400).show().animate({height:SDHarr[5]},'slow');
                    $('.main-navigation ul li').removeClass('hover');
                    $('.main-navigation ul li:eq(5)').addClass('hover');
                }
            };
```

Comment: Your description is talking about an effect when you hover, but your code uses a click handler. Which are you trying to do, hover or click?

Comment: Has your animation finished when you give focus? Else you might want to put the focus part in the animation, so it focusses when done. Sample here: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: nnnnnn - I am using a click handler, but I didn't that that part was entirely relevant as I am just trying to recreate the focus() part.

Yeronimo - I don't think it has finished, as you can see in the code I run the animation using animateToSizeSD(); then shortly after call this "$('.SD-m1 div ul li:first a').focus();". Is that what you meant?

Comment: When you click on an anchor that normally causes navigation, which affects the focus. Your click handler doesn't call `event.preventDefault()` and doesn't `return false;` to prevent the default click behaviour, though perhaps your `href="javascript:;"` would have the same effect.

Comment: Could you post your animateToSizeSD code maybe?

Comment: Sure, posted. Although it is long and I'm aware not the best function ever written.

Comment: @danielblythe you've a selector `$('.main-navigation ul li.mmnu')` in your javascript code but I cant locate an element having class `main-navigation`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry I didn't have it in the code block, now added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show some proper formatting I will use an answer. What I tried to suggest is move the focus call to the animate function like this:

```
$('.expand-SD').show().animate({
        height: SDHarr[0]
    }, 'slow', function () {
        $('.SD-m1 div ul li:first a').focus();
    });
```

This way the focus is executed after the animation has finished.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give this a go very shortly.

Comment: This has worked perfectly. Thank you very much. It never occurred to me that the animation would need to finish before the focus() function would work.